# pushing to a detail view from a table view without storyboard or nib?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, nib, detailview

I am building my first app without using storyboards or nibs.  i want to push to a detail view from a table view and can't seem to find any resources that show how to do this without interface builder.  My table view controller has a picture, title, and subtitle, and i want those all to be passed to the detail view but I want the detail view to have a text description as well.  So far, I have only been able to build my table view controller.  I can't figure out how to do the rest without nib. How do I push to the detail view?  How do I format the detail view?  Does anyone have any resources or sample code I could look at?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a nib file?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not using storyboards or nibs?  There's are good reason why they exist: they make life a WHOLE lot easier.

Comment: it's not that i don't want to use a nib file.  this is for a project i'm working on for which i'm not supposed to use them.

Comment: Wht button do u use to pass to a detail view

Comment: In the past, I have found a few challenges with nibs: 1) understanding the diffs, 2) hooking them up to the code, 3) understanding the magic they do. I've found that using code solves these issues and provides more power while keeping the app size smaller (and thus, download time faster).

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom subclass of UIViewController, e.g., DetailViewController. To format it, write your code in -[DetailViewController viewDidLoad].

So, in DetailViewController.m, you could write:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Add a label with some text.
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 40)];
    label.text = @"Some text";
    [self.view addSubview:label];
}
```

Note: It may be challenging to space out the subviews above in code. Interface Builder helps with this. One idea is to use Interface Builder to space everything out and then just get the coordinates from Interface Builder. You can also use nib2objc.

Then, in -tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: of your table view controller's implementation (.m) file, you could write:

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

self.navigationController won't work if the navigationController is not implemented. I found the new method presentViewController works.

```
DetailViewController *detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
detailVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:detailVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```